# JQuery slideUp() Temporarily Shows Portion of Target Div in Wrong Area of Screen at Beginning of Animation

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown, slideup

Hard to make a good title, but basically my problem is that I have hidden container `<div>` that I want to slideDown() into view when the user clicks the appropriate area of the screen.

When the slide animation starts, for a brief instant, what appears to be the the very right-hand portion of the the stuff in the `<div>` to be "unhidden" flashes on the left hand side of the screen. The animation then completes properly and the everything appears in its proper place. The same thing happens when slideUp() is invoked on the same target.

I'm sure this isn't very helpful without a video to really show the behavior. I was hoping perhaps someone had run into this behavior before and can point me towards what could be causing the issue.

I can post my markup, but it's pretty gnarly.

EDIT:

Wow, well here's my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ct4mQ/

Probably not going to be too helpful because there is way too much dynamic stuff going on in there. Also, no images of course. Anyway, the Jquery stuff in question happens right on the top of the JS section: `// New repair history slider thing

    $('.workbench-category-grid-table-repair-history-slider').toggle(function()`

Comment: Post a jsfiddle - if possible. I think that would really help

Comment: Seen jsfiddle, but never taken the time to really check it out. I'll go see if I can figure it out.

Comment: JSFiddle up. But I don't blame anyone for not wanting to have a go at it.

Comment: I seriously cannot figure out where the problem is from fiddle, but I had encountered a similar problem a while ago. What I did was, added the attribute overflow:hidden to the immediate parent of div to which slide animation I applied. That did help my cause.